# How to get snapshot ref.getDownloadURL()?

Tags: android, dart, flutter, firebase-storage

I make a program to save photo in the Firebase Storage and then take a url and write it to the Firebase database.

```
File sampleImage;
  String changePhoto;

Future getImage() async {
    var tempImage = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      sampleImage = tempImage;
    });
  }

  Future getUrl(name) async
  {
    final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(name);
    changePhoto = await ref.getDownloadURL();
    print(changePhoto);
    return changePhoto;
  }

Widget submitButton() {
    final name = productName.text;
    return RaisedButton(
        textColor: Colors.white,
        color: Color(0xffd50000),
        child: Text("Add"),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
        onPressed: () {
          final StorageReference firebaseStorageRef =
          FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(name);
          final StorageUploadTask task =
          firebaseStorageRef.putFile(sampleImage);
          getUrl(name);
          _bloc.submit(changePhoto);
          print(5);
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
        });
  }
```

But i have problem with

> changePhoto = await ref.getDownloadURL();

because ref.getDownloadURL() returns a dynamic variable. I tried to use

```
Future loadPhoto(name)
  {
    final StorageReference firebaseStorageRef =
    FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(name);
    final StorageUploadTask task =
    firebaseStorageRef.putFile(sampleImage);
  }

onPressed: () {
loadPhoto(name).then((snapshot){
            final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(name);
          changePhoto = snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
            print(changePhoto);
            _bloc.submit(changePhoto);
            print(5);
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          });
```

But it doesn't work. What is my mistake or how I can get snapshot?
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wait to finish upload process like;

```
 var dowurl = await (await uploadTask.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();
```

Comment: In my project writes  'Undefined name UploadTask'. I need to import something or use a newer version?